# Changing the levels of factor to numeric values:

Tags: r

I have a vector with three levels, which are "M", "S", and "unknown"

I want to change them to numeric (integer) values like this:

1. If "M" then value 2 (integer)
2. if "S" then value 1 (integer)
3. if "unknown" then 0 (integer)

#### What I have tried

I was going to change them one by one like this:

```
cards$MaritalStatus[cards$MartialStatus == "M"] <- 2
```

However, I got exception:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, cards$MartialStatus == "M", value = c(1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Any help please?

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character(factor(c("M","S","unknown","M","S"), levels=c('M', 'S', 'unknown'), labels=c(2,1,0)) ))`

Comment: your solution gives me this : `[1] 2 1 0 2 1` actually the bellow answer helps me.

Comment: What is wrong with that solution?  The vector is `v1 <- c('M', 'S', 'unknown', 'M', 'S')`  As per your request, you want to replace 'M' with '2', 'S' with 1 and unknown as '0'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with [match](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html):

```
match(cards$MaritalStatus, c("unknown", "S", "M")) - 1
```

Comment: what will `-1` do in this case please? do you mean that this will minuse one from the position ? if so, where is the insert (update) statement to update my cards$MartialStatus vector please?

Comment: @PaoloRLang the -1 is because the `match` will return 1 for unknown, 2 for S, and 3 for M, while you were asking for 0, 1, and 2 respectively. You can update the column with `cards$MaritalStatus <- match(cards$MaritalStatus, c("unknown", "S", "M")) - 1`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
v1 <- factor(c("M","S","unknown","M","S"))
keyval <- setNames(0:2, c('unknown', 'S', 'M'))
as.numeric(keyval[as.character(v1)])
#[1] 2 1 0 2 1
```

Or

```
as.numeric(as.character(factor(v1, levels=c('M', 'S', 'unknown'),
           labels=c(2,1,0)) ))
#[1] 2 1 0 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't take this approach if you had more than 3 values but in this case you could use a nested ifelse statement like so:

```
ifelse(cards$MaritalStatus=="unknown", 0, ifelse(cards$MaritalStatus=="M", 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general approach (and maybe easier to understand):

1st - declare values and what they should be changed to.

```
namesList <- list(M=2, A=1, unknown=0)
```

2nd - apply changes

```
unlist(namesList[as.character(cards$MaritalStatus)])
```